# Can SignalR contain controller logic and perform CRUD operations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, crud

I am building an E-Commerce website using ASP.Net Core 3.1 MVC and I am using SignalR to provide real-time statistics to the admin dashboard. My aim is to make the dashboard CRUD operations completely asynchronous. So my question is, can SignalR be used to perform CRUD operations instead of using AJAX to call controller actions and if yes, how can a hub contain controller logic since the controller class exposes extra functionality and does this considered to be a good practice in a production environment?

Comment: You can do this, but why? Under normal circumstances, you only need to inject hubcontext into the controller, and still implement crud in the controller's action. When you savechange is complete, you can call the signalr method and pass it to the client for real-time updates.You can refer to this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1#inject-an-instance-of-ihubcontext-in-a-controller

Comment: @YongqingYu I am aware of this, in fact, I am using this approach right now, I was just wondering since I have an open SignalR connection could I do all the crud work through it rather than doing the POST via AJAX and then updating the clients via SignalR. the whole idea came to me when thinking of using a single way to communicate rather than 2

Comment: You can do this, but it is not necessary. You just complicate it. You can keep the original logic code, and then add the signalR method on this basis.